# [solved] UWsim installscene.sh command not found

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just start with ROS and UWsim

I am trying to install new scenes because i want to modified a scene for my project.

I follow the guide on this answer

> http://answers.ros.org/question/234836/uwsim-unable-to-execute-scene-installer-script-for-package-based-installation-of-uw-sim/

I download the sh file from this link

> http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/files/scenes/installScene

then

copy and paste the file into the path

```
/opt/ros/indigo/share/uwsim/data/scenes
```

Then I try to run the line:

```
sudo /opt/ros/indigo/share/uwsim/data/scenes/installScene.sh -s pipes_scene.uws
```

and I get:

> root@wilmer-VirtualBox:~# sudo
> /opt/ros/indigo/share/uwsim/data/scenes/installScene.sh
> -s pipes_scene.uws sudo: /opt/ros/indigo/share/uwsim/data/scenes/installScene.sh:
> command not found

what am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242206/%5Bsolved%5D-uwsim-installscene.sh-command-not-found/) by [Wilmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27812/wilmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason the saved file was not been recognized as a command i download from other source and moved to the folder

---

Originally posted by [Wilmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27812/wilmer/) with karma: 18 on 2016-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-08-23**:
You can mark this as solved by clicking the check mark next to your answer.

**Comment by [Wilmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27812/wilmer/) on 2016-08-30**:
No, i can't because I don't have 10 points

**Comment by [Hossein92](https://answers.ros.org/users/34817/hossein92/) on 2018-04-25**:
guys i have this problem too, what should i do?